# SQL query joining tables - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Take an example from sample HR schema. What would be query for finding employees which do not have LOCATION_ID = 1700 
I have tried a query using inner join but i don't know how to go further.
The resulting query should something be like

```
select * from employees
inner join  departments on
    employees.DEPARTMENT_ID=departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
-->  and where departments.location_id != '1700'
```

Since i am taking HR schema as an example. I would like to add that in my original case location_id is a varchar2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want query in Sql

```
select * from employees
    inner join  departments on
      employees.DEPARTMENT_ID=departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
where departments.location_id <> 1700
```

Comment: Oracle supports both != and <> to indicate not equal to.  The actual error, that this answer corrects, is that "and where" is not valid syntax for any database.  Oh, by the way, even though this works, since department_id is varchar, it should be quoted.